# Phenotype - r coading in r studio

Tags: r

I wrote this part of code in R:

1) Your program should download the GeoData from the database and
creates a Heatmap.

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

biocLite("GEOquery")

library(Biobase)

library(GEOquery)

gds<-getGEO('GDS4057',destdir='.')

eset<-GDS2eSet(gds,do.log2=TRUE)

myData<-exprs(eset)
heatmap(myData[1:20,])
```

2) After, it identifies the phenotype characteristic if our sample is ER +
(ERpos) or ER- (ERneg) and keeps only those samples. And at this point
You must create a heatmap with the selected samples.

```
genoData <- gds@dataTable@columns$`genotype/variation`

View(genoData)

reduced<-myData[, genoData%in%c("ER (IHC): +","ER (IHC): -")]

heatmap(reduced[1:20, ])
```

3) In these samples will implement your algorithm for discretization

```
reduced[is.na(reduced)] <- 0

reduced2 <- reduced

for(i in 1:nrow(reduced)){

  myMean <- mean(reduced[i,])

  for(j in 1:ncol(reduced)){

    if (reduced[i,j] < myMean)

      reduced2[i,j] = 0

    else 

      reduced2[i,j] = 1

  }
}
```

4)Create a polarity-score for each gene (details below).

```
for(i in 1:nrow(reduced2)){

  for(j in 1:ncol(reduced2)){

    if(reduced2[i,j]==1 &&  something to search if this gene is plus(+) ->("ER (IHC): +"))

       print("hello")
  }
}
```

!POLARITY SCORE

r = ((a/(a+c))-(b/(b+d))) / ((a/(a+c))+(b/(b+d)))

- a = the number of samples ER+ with value 1
- b = the number of samples ER- with value 1
- c = the number of samples ER+ with value 0
- d = the number of samples ER- with value 0

and my problem is that in the last `if` i want to check if my `reduced2` cell `[i][j]` is 1 and if the phenotype in this cell is '+' ....

Comment: Can you provide us a tiny subset of your `reduced2`? Just 5 rows and column would be fine. Something like `dput(reduced2[1:5,1:5])` should be fine as long as it has the phenotype field.

Comment: > dput(reduced2[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("1007_s_at", 
"1053_at", "117_at", "121_at", "1255_g_at"), 
c("GSM549289", "GSM549291", 
"GSM549274", "GSM750738", "GSM750748")))